# How send only first fieldset data on clicking button in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

This is short code of my project.
I just want send data of only first fieldset after clicking on button not second fieldset.

```
 <form id="myform" [formGroup]="signupForm">

 <fieldset>

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Full name" formControlName="userName" required >
    <mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.get('userName').hasError('required')">
         Full Name is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button (click)="onCheck(signupForm.value)">Next</button>

    </fieldset>

<fieldset>

    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Full name" formControlName="userName" required >
    <mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.get('userName').hasError('required')">
         Full Name is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formControlNames share the same name. Seems to be the root of evil.

Comment: i have just copy pasted that. my original form has 10 fields . 5 fields in first fieldset and others are in second fieldset. i am hiding 2nd fieldset using jquery.i just want send only first fieldset data after clicking on on button